# Select2 not returning any data, just display searching

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery-select2

i'm using codeigniter and select2 plugin for displaying my data.. but i have a problem, that plugin not display anything, just display searching... there is my code

```
/*------------- JS -----------------*/
$("‪#‎nm_peg‬").select2({
placeholder: "Masukkan Nama Pegawai",
width:'element',
ajax : {
url : "<?php echo site_url('pegawai/getAllData'); ?>",
dataType: 'json',
data: function (term, page) {
return {
q: term
};
},
results: function (data, page) {
return { results: data };
}
}
});
```

this is my controller

```
/*-------------- Controller ---------------*/
public function getAllData()
{
$this->load->model('pegawaimodel');
$d = $this->pegawaimodel->get_all_pegawai();
$rows = array();
foreach ($d as $a) {
$rows[] = $a;
}
header('Content-Type:application/json');
return json_encode($d);
}
```

and this is my model.

```
/*--------------Model-----------------*/
public function get_all_pegawai()
{ 
$this->db->select('peg_id, peg_nama');
$this->db->from('master_pegawai');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

thank's for any help..

Comment: Do you receive the data after ajax loaded?

Comment: Is your javascript on a separate .js file ? If so, you can't use <?php echo site_url('pegawai/getAllData'); ?>.

Comment: Remove quotes above url in ajax object. Also, make sure that JS snippet is in the PHP file (i.e. search.php) and not in JS file which can't be read by PHP parser.